# The proper use of RezChecker color

Tags: color-management, color-correction, camera, icc-profile

I am not sure how much my question is relavent to this forum but I guess it must be the right place.

Basically my question to you is, if you have any prior knowledge about color checkers and color calibration, what is the proper use of RezChecker that makes it different from other color checkers (beside the size)?

Personally, I can notice that the color patches on RezChecker are kinda paler and have different tones than the ones on x-rite or GretagMacbeth. Given that I assumed it may be more appropriate for color calibration in the (oil) painting domain.

It is only my speculation. I would like to hear something more scientific.

[image]